# How to change "Image style" of an Image field in a given view mode programmatically (as on "Manage display" tab after clicking the gear)?

Tags: 7, media

**I would like to change the *"Image style"* of some Image fields** in some given view modes, which are attached to particular content types; I would like to do this **programmatically**.

This is what I would like to change:

[image: Changing the Image style of an Image field in a given view mode]

How should I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this should do it:

```
$entity_type = 'node';
$bundle = 'article';
$field_name = 'field_image';
$view_mode = 'default';

// Get the instance info
$instance_info = field_info_instance($entity_type, $field_name, $bundle);

// Change the image style
$instance_info['display'][$view_mode]['settings']['image_style'] = 'new_image_style';

// Save it
field_update_instance($instance_info);
```

Comment: Where could I place this code? in template.php? or where? thanks.